# Using Android's MediaPlayer class, play an audio file (google drive/drop box/zoho docs)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, google-drive-android-api

I have an app on google play store that displays a book content. I am trying to embed audio feature for the app. But the audio files would increase the size of the app drastically.

So, I am thinking to store the audio files in Google Drive / Drop Box or Zoho Docs and use Media Player class to stream and play the audio file. But it does not work. It throws FileNotFound Exception. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

if (mbAudioOn)
{
    try
    {
        if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
        mPlayer.setDataSource("https://www.dropbox.com/s/avvy670dxc76y80/audio_02.m4a");
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is error?have you uploaded your audio in dropbox properly?

Comment: Yes. I can access the file from browser. You can just copy and paste the URL on your browser and you will be able to listen to the audio. The error is this **Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://docs.zoho.com/file/033zq825c9f2b1f5642578e3d00432e38a425**

Answer (score 0):

I think this used to be doable in Google Drive before when hosting was still supported by Google Drive. This [SO thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/65763/how-can-i-hotlink-an-mp3-in-google-drive-with-a-url-ending-in-mp3) shares a way to do that. However, in [Google's blog post](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2015/08/deprecating-web-hosting-support-in.html), web hosting is now deprecated, August 21, 2016 being the official date. So Google Drive is no longer the option for this.

Comment: Someone mentioned I can use Firebase (https://firebase.google.com/). Is it feasible?

Comment: If you're talking about Firebase Hosting, it's for web apps, very different from what you're trying to do. Try Dropbox.

Comment: Check this [demo that I've done in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b64hcrt9/4/). If this is what you're trying to do, then it's doable. Make sure you're signed in to Google account in your browser